# What is the easiest method to get the selection in input text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getselection

How could I get the selected text in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/fjkSK/) ?

I working with Firefox 3.6.3 (currently not interested in other browsers).

HTML:

```
<input id="my_text_field" type="text" />
<div id="log"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#my_text_field").select(function() {
   var selected_text = "Something selected"; // What should be here ?
   $("#log").append(selected_text + "<br />");
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get selected text from textbox control with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this plugin:

http://labs.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.2.3-test/test.html

Comment: Sad, its offline. Has anyone downloaded version 0.2.3 and is able to obtain it? EDIT: Found: http://alexcompiler.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/trunk/javascript/jquery-fieldselection.js

Comment: Ok, found again: http://www.programmierer-forum.de/jquery-fieldselection-by-alex-brem-v0-2-3-last-cange-2006-12-20-t316789.htm

Answer (score 2):

Check out this other SO post. Hope this helps. ;)

[How to get selected text from textbox control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript)