# how to apply javascript to selected text of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to apply some changes to the selected text of a text area only.

I want to select a certain portion of a text written in the text area and want to make some changes on it by javascript.

Thanks

Comment: I think the answer to this question might help you:

[how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.selection.createRange().text = "NEW TEXT";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question might help you:

[how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript)

It shows you selection of the text and you can use javascript to process it.