# How to get jQuery "on-select-off" event

Tags: jquery

We have a simple textarea and a button.

```
<input type="button" id ="foo" disabled>
<textarea rows="12" name="message" id="message" cols="50"></textarea>
```

I need to:

1. remove attribute **disabled** from button when some text in textarea selected
2. set attribute **disabled** when selection canceled

First task was achieved with this code:`$('textarea').select(function() {
$('#foo').attr('disabled','');});`

But with the second task i havn't any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code
`$(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea').select(function() {$('#foo').attr('disabled',false)});
        $('textarea').mousedown(function() { $('#foo').attr('disabled',true);});
    });`
Could you try using focus event?
Seems this event will be trigger once focusing on your DOM element.
answer was NO. you can use mouse down.

Comment: Button should be enabled only when some text in textarea selected. Focus event and onMouseUp aren't a right choice.

Comment: I use mousedown event.Otherwise, we can also use focus event like below answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

Comment: With some dances with tambourine it works the right way. I thought there was real event in jQuery. Or at least select possibility to use two functions inside, like $('textarea').select(fn1{ text selected },fn2{ text unselected });

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#controlId").attr('disabled','disabled');  //disable the control

      $("#controlId").removeAttr('disabled');//remove disabled
   });
</script>
```

**Don't do** `$("#Div").attr('disabled','true');`, the main problem here is that with 1.6 (or sth around that) the comparison with `== true` is broken, if the attributes value is `disabled` (see http://jsfiddle.net/2vene/1/ (and switch the jquery-version)). You should rather go for [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/%C2%B4).

You can check [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F).

Comment: or for `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Thanks for "disabled" info, but the main question is how to disable "when selection of some text is cancelled".

Comment: On Cancel event you do `$("#controlId").removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: aaahhh :) stealing my hint and my fiddle and not giving any credits ... don't do that!

Comment: Learned something from you and now sharing :)

Comment: assimilating knowledge and paying homage to the "teacher" are two completely different things :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected text using this function,

```
 function getSelectedText() {
        var text = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {
            text = "" + window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange &&
                document.selection.type == "Text") {
            text = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return text;
    }
```

And add new function like this in mouse up event,

```
function  Disable() { 
   if(getSelectedText()=='')
   {
      $('#foo').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
}

$('textarea').mouseup(Disable);
```

Comment: Will it refers for selection of any text on page or only for this textarea?

Comment: Yes I think. I haven't tested. There would be a way to get the selected text from the text box too.

Comment: Here it is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript