# Bold selected text in text area using java script

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, getelementbyid

Simply tying to bold selected text within the text area

Here my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Bold() {
    document.getElementById('firstTextarea').value = 'bold';
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="firstTextarea" rows="12" cols="40"></textarea>
<button onclick="Bold();">Bold</button>
```

Comment: You're setting the wrong attribute of the textarea element. See udidu's answer.

Comment: You might want to look at this post here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

Comment: This is not possible in a standard textarea elemento. You will have to use a div with editable html or an WYSIWYG editor like ckeditor, cleditor or tiny MCE.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `value` attribute of that Textarea field. What you want to set is the `font-weight` attribute which is done like this:

`document.getElementById('firstTextarea').style.fontWeight = 'bold';`

Comment: it doesn't bold bold the selected text but all text instead

Comment: Does that mean that the answer is you should bold all text ?

Comment: well thanks for the input but that didnt work at all, didnt even bold the text in the text area, although could be an issues with my button

Comment: @user2104513.. try to change you'r font to something else.. the default font (monospace) for `textarea` sometimes look like normal if its bold...

Comment: @jonasnas, No, if you want to highlight the selected text you should use something else instead of the `textarea`..

Comment: any idea to  what I should do instead, nothing to complicated

Comment: It's OK. All I'm saying is the question was about a selected text.