# If text is selected, and dropdown option is clicked, change color of selected text

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, selection

I want to make a text editor, and when you select some text in the text area, then click an option from the drop down, the selected text from the text area changes color.  Unfortunately I don't know how to do this because when I try to access the drop down, the selection from the text area disappears.

**jsFiddle** :: http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/a77sM/

```
function GetSelectedText () {
  if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
      var range = window.getSelection ();
      var selection = range.toString();
      alert(selection);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing around with trying to change color of highlighted content within the textarea, but it seems that you cannot change the color of text within a textarea.  An alternative, as has been suggested before, is to create an editable div that acts as a rich textbox.  You can set the contentEditable property on the div to true in order for this to work.  Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpFGf/3/) if you want to play around with it.

And here is my JS code.  I changed a couple things on the HTML too so check out the jsfiddle for the full code.

```
function GetSelectedText (origtext, seltext, tcolor) {
    //alert(origtext + ", " + seltext + ", " + tcolor);
    var divcontent = document.getElementById('sec');
    var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
    var selIndex = origtext.indexOf(seltext);
    var selLength = seltext.length;

    //split the text to insert a span with a new color
    var fpart = origtext.substr(0, selIndex);
    var spart = origtext.substr(selIndex + selLength);
    //alert(fpart + ", " + spart);

    // add the text that was highlighted and set the color
    spanTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(seltext));
    spanTag.style.color = tcolor;

    //remove all the children of the div
    while(divcontent.hasChildNodes()){
         divcontent.removeChild(divcontent.lastChild);   
    }

    //append the original text with the highlighted part
    divcontent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fpart));
    divcontent.appendChild(spanTag);
    divcontent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(spart));
} 

// this function was found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

function getTextFieldSelection() {
    var textComponent = document.getElementById('content');
    var selectElem = document.getElementById("myselect");

    var selectedText;
    // IE version
    if (document.selection != undefined)
    {
         textComponent.focus();
         var sel = document.selection.createRange();
         selectedText = sel.text;
    }
    // Mozilla version
    else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
    {
         var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
         var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
         selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    //alert("You selected: " + selectedText);
    selectElem.onchange = GetSelectedText(textComponent.value, selectedText,selectElem.options[selectElem.selectedIndex].text.toLowerCase());
}

var content = document.getElementById("content");
var selectElem = document.getElementById("myselect");

selectElem.onfocus = function (e) { getTextFieldSelection(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you click the select element it steals focus from textarea.
You have to give back the focus to textarea element, here is a working example (at least in chrome):

```
var color   = document.getElementById("color"), // this is the select element
    content = document.getElementById("content");

color.onfocus = function (){ content.focus(); };
```