# How to remove selected text from an input Text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

If there is highlighted text inside of a text input, how do I remove the selected text?

I set up a fiddle to show how far I got, but I can't figure out how to remove the given text.

```html
<input type='text' value='stackoverflow.com' id='text1' />
<br />
<button id="btnSelect">select text</button>
<button id="btnRemove">remove selected text</button>
```

Comment: press backspace or delete

Comment: <input type='text' value='' id='text1' />. Set value blank.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are there to get selected text from `input` tag ..
check the demo

```js
$("#btnSelect").click(function () {
    document.getElementById('txtbox').setSelectionRange(6, 12);
});
$("#btnRemove").click(function () {
    var ele  = document.getElementById('txtbox');
    var text = ele.value;
    
    text = text.slice(0, ele.selectionStart) + text.slice(ele.selectionEnd);
    ele.value = text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value='stackoverflow.com' id='txtbox' />
<br />
<button id="btnSelect">select text</button>
<button id="btnRemove">remove selected text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function removeText()
{
 document.getElementById('text1').value  = "";
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='stackoverflow.com' id='text1' />
<br />
<button id="btnSelect">select text</button>
<button id="btnRemove" onclick="removeText()">remove selected text</button>
```

Comment: OP just want to remove the selected text and not the entire value.