# Selected text box value only alert

Tags: jquery

Suppose my textBox Value is "Hello, How are you?" and when I select **How are you?** then I want selected text in an alert box.

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: use `split` method..... or `indexOf` method with `slice`(`substr` or `substring`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected text from textbox control with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks for reply me!
I got it answer here what i want exatly.  http://jsfiddle.net/rT5vR/

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection) there is no difference between `window.getSelection()` and `document.getSelection()`.