# How to get highlighted text position from textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the selected text position using javascript. For example,

I have a simple textarea.

```css
#input-text {
  resize: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input-text">I am a student and I want to become a good person</textarea>
```

In my textarea, I have some text such as:

```
"I am a student and I want to become a good person"
```

From this string, if I select "become a good person" from the textarea, 

Then How can I get the selected text/ string position in javascript?



*Here the selected string character starts from 29 and ends in 49. So the start position is 29 & the end position is 49*

Comment: By position you mean what is the index of character "b" of "become" in the string?

Comment: I feel like the question is just asking for [HTMLInputElement.selectionStart](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/HTMLInputElement/selectionStart/) and [selectionEnd](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/HTMLInputElement/selectionEnd/) while the answers mostly talk about the selection event. No point in writing an answer that's included in all the other answers, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get selected text from textbox control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will work for text selection with the mouse and keyboard for all `<textarea>` elements on the page.
Change the selector (be more specific) if you don't want all `<textarea>` elements to have this text selection.

Read the comments, you will find out there how to disable keyboard selection,  if you don't want/need keyboard selection.

```js
var mySelection = function (element) {
    let startPos = element.selectionStart;
    let endPos = element.selectionEnd;
    let selectedText = element.value.substring(startPos, endPos);

    if(selectedText.length <= 0) {
      return; // stop here if selection length is <= 0
    }
    
    // log the selection
    console.log("startPos: " + startPos, " | endPos: " + endPos );
    console.log("selectedText: " +  selectedText);

  };

var textAreaElements = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
[...textAreaElements].forEach(function(element) {
    // register "mouseup" event for the mouse
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
        mySelection(element)
    });
    
    // register "keyup" event for the keyboard
    element.addEventListener('keyup', function( event ) {
        // assuming we need CTRL, SHIFT or CMD key to select text
        // only listen for those keyup events
        if(event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 17 || event.metaKey) {
            mySelection(element)
        }
    });
});
```

```css
textarea {
   resize: none; 
   width: 75%;
   height: 50px; 
   margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea>I am a student and I want to become a good person</textarea>
```

Comment: This doesn't fire if you select using the keyboard rather than the mouse.

Comment: @curiousdannii I've updated the answer, now it also works with keyboard selection

Answer (score 5):

I would make use of of **onselect** event to get the same.

```
<textarea id="input-text" onselect="myFunction(event)">I am a student and I want to become a good person</textarea>


<script>
    function myFunction(event) {
      const start  = event.currentTarget.selectionStart;
      const end= event.currentTarget.selectionEnd;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Caramba answer worked pretty great, however I had the issue that if you selected some text and released the mouse *outside* of the textarea, the event didn't fire.

To solve this i changed the initial event to `mousedown`, this event registers a `mouseup` event on the document to ensure it fires after the cursor is released. The `mouseup` event then removes itself after it has fired.

This can be achieved with adding the `once` option to `addEventListener`, but sadly isn't supported in IE11 which is why i used the solution in the snippet.

```js
var mySelection = function (element) {
    let startPos = element.selectionStart;
    let endPos = element.selectionEnd;
    let selectedText = element.value.substring(startPos, endPos);

    if(selectedText.length <= 0) {
      return; // stop here if selection length is <= 0
    }
    
    // log the selection
    console.log("startPos: " + startPos, " | endPos: " + endPos );
    console.log("selectedText: " +  selectedText);
};

function addSelfDestructiveEventListener (element, eventType, callback) {
    let handler = () => {
        callback();
        element.removeEventListener(eventType, handler);
    };
    element.addEventListener(eventType, handler);
};

var textAreaElements = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
[...textAreaElements].forEach(function(element) {
    // register "mouseup" event for those
    element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
      // This will only run the event once and then remove itself
      addSelfDestructiveEventListener(document, 'mouseup', function() {
        mySelection(element)
      })
    });
    
    // register "keyup" event for the keyboard
    element.addEventListener('keyup', function( event ) {
        // assuming we need CTRL, SHIFT or CMD key to select text
        // only listen for those keyup events
        if(event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 17 || event.metaKey) {
            mySelection(element)
        }
    });
});
```

```css
textarea {
   resize: none; 
   width: 50%;
   height: 50px; 
   margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea>I am a student and I want to become a good person</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var idoftextarea='answer';
    function getSelectedText(idoftextarea){
        var textArea = document.getElementById(idoftextarea);
        var text =textArea.value;
        var indexStart=textArea.selectionStart;
        var indexEnd=textArea.selectionEnd;
        alert(text.substring(indexStart, indexEnd));

    }


    getSelectedText(idoftextarea);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySelection = function (element) {
let startPos = element.selectionStart;
let endPos = element.selectionEnd;
let selectedText = element.value.substring(startPos, endPos);

if(selectedText.length <= 0) {
  return; // stop here if selection length is <= 0
}

// log the selection
console.log("startPos: " + startPos, " | endPos: " + endPos );
console.log("selectedText: " +  selectedText); };var textAreaElements = document.querySelectorAll('textarea'); 
[...textAreaElements].forEach(function(element) {
// register "mouseup" event for the mouse
element.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    mySelection(element)
});
// register "keyup" event for the keyboard
element.addEventListener('keyup', function( event ) {
    // assuming we need CTRL, SHIFT or CMD key to select text
    // only listen for those keyup events
    if(event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 17 || event.metaKey) {
        mySelection(element)
    }
});});
```

Comment: Can you please add a little explanation to what you code does?