# How to get the current text selection with Javascript on ANY part of the website?

Tags: javascript, selection

I'd like to get the selected text from a website, but when I use `document.getSelection` it does not work for selections inside textareas and to get the selection from a text area I would need to know which textarea has the selection to use the textarea functions. Is there a simple methods for getting the current selection or do I need to iterate over all elements to test if they contain selected text?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-a-textbox-control-with-javascript?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78183126/edit) the question to include a [mre]: code demonstrating the HTML structure with the expected selection range and desired text content result?

Comment: @jsejcksn I am writing a userscript and I want it to work on *any* page for any selection the user may make.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No. Or maybe partially, but this would mean: 1) look for selections in the page using `getSelection` 2) Iterate over all textareas to get the selection there 3) Check all text inputs 4) The types of selection that may still be missing after the two steps.

Answer (score 2):

**Selection of text in general document content and in user input elements are mutually exclusive.**

- HTMLTextAreaElement and HTMLInputElement both have `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties which are offsets of selected text in their content
- INPUT elements which don't support selection return `null` for the selection start/end properties.
- If `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` have the same value there is no selection within the element, and if the values are numeric it give the position of the cursor in the element.
- If you click elsewhere on the page, INPUT and TEXTAREA elements lose focus and and any selected text in their content is deselected.
- `document.activeElement` holds a reference to the currently focused element. A `null` value indicates the user has clicked outside web page content in the browser, possibly to change tabs. The `tagName` property of a non-null `activeElement` indicates what kind of element it is in upper case.

Putting all of this together I would start with a function similar to that below - it returns null if the page if the  not in focus or an INPUT element that doesn't support selection is in focus. Otherwise it returns one of two types of object: either a selection object or a custom object containing details of user input with a `type` property set to "UIText".

```
function getCurrentSelection() {
  let selection;

  const active = document.activeElement;
  if(!active) return null;

  let tagName = active.tagName;
  if( tagName == "INPUT" || tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
    const {selectionStart, selectionEnd} = active;
    selection = selectionStart === null ? null : {
     type: "UIText",
     element: active,
     tag: tagName,
     selectionStart,
     selectionEnd,
     text: active.value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd)
    };
   }
   else {
      selection = document.getSelection()
   }
   return selection;
}
```